# Return is not being placed at right block

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and trying out a small code exercise, i am having a bit of trouble in doing `return` at a certain else block. The below code takes a number and multiplies each digit until the result is single digit.

What am i doing wrong ?

```
def persis(n):
    convert_str = str(n)
    indi_num = [int(i) for i in convert_str ]
    result = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, indi_num)

    #######
    final = None
    new_result = str(result)
    new_indi_num = [int(i) for i in new_result]

    if len(new_indi_num) > 1:
        persis(int(new_result))

    else:
        print "FINAL RESULT IS: "+str(new_indi_num)
        ## return str(new_indi_num) # This Returns None From here##


pas=persis(162)
print pas
```

This Prints me

```
FINAL RESULT IS: [2]
None
```

Comment: Place your return at the same identation level as the `else` statement.

Comment: @MaximilianPeters still says None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
from functools import reduce

def persis(n):
    convert_str = str(n)
    indi_num = [int(i) for i in convert_str ]
    result = reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, indi_num)

    #######
    final = None
    new_result = str(result)
    new_indi_num = [int(i) for i in new_result]

    if len(new_indi_num) > 1:
        return persis(int(new_result))

    else:
        print "FINAL RESULT IS: "+str(new_indi_num[0])
        return new_indi_num[0]


pas=persis(162)
print pas
```

This prints

```
FINAL RESULT IS: 2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `persis(int(new_result))` to `return persis(int(new_result))` (and you need to uncomment the original `return` statement).

This is a recursive function. What's happening is that there are at least two calls to this function: a "parent" call that enters the `if` statement and makes another call (the child call) to `persis`, and a child call that is called by the parent and enters the else block. Once you uncomment the return statement, the child call will correctly return the value you desire; however, it returns this value to the parent, which doesn't do anything with it. By changing `persis(int(new_result))` to `return persis(int(new_result))` you make sure that the parent call returns the same thing as the child.